# Auto git pull after pushing from local repository

Tags: git, repository

I have openhab2 running on Raspberry Pi and I would like to work on config files remotely with version control.

I have git set up on server and made git init in /etc/openhab2. I can see all the files in github. When i change file in github and run git pull on server, files update as they should and vice versa. Now I want to try push from local repo. It only makes changes in github. I have to manually run git pull on server to apply those changes on server. I tried to set hooks (post-receive method) to autopull from github repository in /etc/openhab2/.git/hooks/post-receive. Then I set up permissions for executing this file.

post-receive script:

```py
cd /etc/openhab2/
unset GIT_DIR
git pull
```

When I change file in VS code and push from github desktop, it updates that file only on github, but not on server. Again I have to manually run git pull on server to apply changes. I have to misunderstood something. Can you please help me ?

Comment: I abandoned this method. Instead I use sitemap with button (exec binding, executing .sh script) to pull config files from github repo.

Answer (score 0):

first of all run:

```
git status
```

this will show you the branch that you are on, let`s say for now it's master.
so now run:

```
git push origin master
```

if you added new file(s) to your project run:

```
git add .
```

this will add those new file(s)
the next step is to commit those changes:

```
git commit -am 'your comments go here about this commit'
```

then you need to pull again the files from the server' if they where changed by someone else from your team and you don`t no that:

```
git pull origin master
```

then push the changes:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: It looks like the hook is never executed